# Truncate Table `inventory_reservation`

Tags: magento2.3, msi

How much risk is to truncate table `inventory_reservation` ?

After truncate does MSI will work fine or Do i need to bang my head on keyboard !!?

Comment: well, I would advise to backup first before doing anything

Comment: That I'll obviously do but what about risk After watching MSI modules I think this table responsible for maintian qty and now I'm ready to push store to production. but products count for salable qty is mismatched. I think its due to some customer removed after placing order or incomplete order.

Comment: @Vivek Reservation inconsistency tool may help you with these inconsistencies - https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/wiki/CLI-Reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Truncating reservation table you may break the Salability Quantity calculation for your products. Thus, it's discouraged to apply any changes to this table manually employing direct SQL queries. Here you can read more about that - https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/wiki/Salable-Quantity-Calculation-and-Mechanism-of-Reservations

You may run the Reservation Cleanup command by CRON to make this table cleaning up periodically. More info about this here - https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/wiki/CLI-Reference

Answer (score 2):

In some instances, it might make sense to do so. We have had occasions where some reported salable inventory amounts are off (haven't tracked down how it happens). If we make sure all orders are processed, reload all inventory amounts from our inventory management system, then we can safely truncate the table to clear up any inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

Truncating the inventory_reservation table worked like a charm in clearing all the reservations it places on the stock.

The issue for us was that we use a SAP system which updates the website with live stock levels in our warehouse, so it was annoying that M2 was keeping its own tally, as it was not matching ours.

The reason for the mismatching is that quite alot of our orders are small items that are sent via royal mail without tracking, so we didnt have any tracking information and so didnt create shipments for alot of orders, as our SAP system handles all of that. But not creating shipments in M2 meant that the orders were not getting closed off in M2, they were still in processing mode. This is what causes the mismatch - M2 keeps the reservation in place until the order has been shipped.

In short, always close off every single order, otherwise you will accumulate alot of mismatched stock quantities. but if you need to, truncating the inventory_reservation table is pretty safe, as its just a self contained record of reservations, so long as you handle your shipments outside of M2. Otherwise there is no need to truncate this table.