# Is it ok to Truncate the "inventory_reservation" table

Tags: magento2, msi

I have Magento 2.3.6 with MSI enabled.

What are the consequences that can occur after truncating the "inventory_reservation" table?

Is it ok to truncate the "inventory_reservation" table?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/277267/36463

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trunacate Table \`inventory\_reservation\`](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277026/trunacate-table-inventory-reservation)

Comment: @KeyurShah, not exactly I want to know what are the consequences that can occur after truncating "inventory_reservation" table, I saw the below issue on GitHub github.com/magento/magento2/issues/30021

Answer (score 1):

It will reset your salable qty value. After deleting records from this table, salable quantity will be equal to quantity.

Comment: This is correct but what are the consequences that can occur, I saw the below issue on GitHub
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/30021